# Unable to fix the error while inserting records into database using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public class StudentDataPersistence {

    public void insertStudentInfo(Student student) {

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
        String username = "system";
        String password = "Data03@";
        Connection connection = null;
        //Statement statement = null;

        try {
            //Step 1 : Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            //Step 2 : Open a connection  
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to oracle");
            }

            //Step 3 : Write code to map Java Object to the Student_Info table
            System.out.println("Inserting records into the database");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into Student_Info " +
                    "VALUES(student.getName(),student.getRoll_no(),student.getAddress(),student.getPhone_no())";
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Inserted student information into the database");

        } catch (SQLException se) {

            //handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Inside the finally block");
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("!GoodBye");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("Bavin", 1, "Umar Nagar", "89898989809");
        StudentDataPersistence obj = new StudentDataPersistence();
        obj.insertStudentInfo(student);
    }

}
```

The error it shows it :

Connecting to a selected database...
Connected to oracle
Inserting records into the database
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "STUDENT"."GETPHONE_NO": invalid identifier

```
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:189)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:242)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:554)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1478)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java:888)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.java:2076)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteOther(OracleStatement.java:1986)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2697)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1035)
at org.core.hibernate.reason.StudentDataPersistence.insertStudentInfo(StudentDataPersistence.java:52)
at org.core.hibernate.reason.StudentDataPersistence.main(StudentDataPersistence.java:80)
```

Inside the finally block
!GoodBye

All the answers (those of you who illustrate it with an oracle query) in reply were wrong.
Kindly do have a look at it before posting.
the correct one i got when i posted another thread  regarding the same:

String query =  "insert into Student_Info(name,roll_no,address,phone_no) VALUES('"+student.getName()+"',"+student.getRoll_no()+",'"+student.getAddress()+"','"+student.getPhone_no()+"')";

Answer (score 0):

you have commented out your Statement object definition. So the statement object is unknown when you're using it.
uncomment this line:

```
//Statement statement;
```

And as earlier pointed out by @putaro, you need to quote certain parts of your SQL query.

```
String sql = "insert into Student_Info " +
                    "VALUES("+student.getName()+","+student.getRoll_no()+","+student.getAddress()+","+student.getPhone_no()+")";
```

This is to insert the actual object values into the query. Things within the quote would be inserted as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Error ORA-00904 means Oracle does not know the identifier "STUDENT"."GETPHONE_NO" it looks like you are trying to insert some value to a column named "GetPhone_NO" to Table "Student" from your SQL. so you should check your SQL and table structure again

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two problems in the code.

1. Currently your code is not using the student object while making the query. All student.getName() etc call taken as plain strings rather than method calls that returns the appropriate values.
2. Second it would be better to write the query in the following form. It will avoid silly errors because of the structure of the tables.

> "INSERT INTO student_info(name,roll_no,address,phone) VALUES("+
>   student.getName()+"," +
>   student.getRoll_no()+","+student.getAddress()+","+student.getPhone_no()+")";

Even better is if you use prepared statement like

Try changing the query like

"INSERT INTO student_info(name,roll_no,address,phone) VALUES(?,?,?,?)"

and then set the parameter values.